# Update product price if specific meta_key contains a specific meta_value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In Wordpress / Woocommerce database there is a `wp_postmeta` table.

I am try to update the `meta_value = '0'` where `meta_key = '_price'` only if another `meta_key = 'group'` and `meta_value = 'glass'` exist for the same `post_id`.

This is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '0'
WHERE meta_key = '_price' AND meta_key = 'group' AND meta_value = 'glass';
```

And This one too:

```
  UPDATE 
        `wp_postmeta` 
    SET 
        `meta_value` = '0' 
    WHERE 
        meta_key = '_price' 
        AND `meta_key` IN (
            SELECT 
                `meta_value` = 'glass' 
            FROM 
                `wp_postmeta`
        );
```

Those attempts doesn't work.

How can I update the `meta_value = '0'` (for `meta_key = '_price'`) only if the `meta_key = 'group'` and `meta_value = 'glass'` exist for the same `post_id`?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Can you give a bit of context about where the code you pasted comes from and where it is implemented. Are you trying to change a plugin or is that homegrown code? Which hooks are you relying on; What is the error that you have? Is it a SQL question or Woocommerce or a Wordpress question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta as pm
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2 on pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
SET pm.meta_value = '0'
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_price'
AND pm2.meta_key = 'group' 
AND pm2.meta_value = 'glass';
```

it should work

Comment: Thank you so much and have a nice day! Works like a charm)

Comment: @OrkhanHasanli Welcome … It's not easy for all skilled SQL fellows here to understand the specificities of Wordpress / Woocommerce, when they are not used to.